# electric field due to a square loop via algebraic instead of symmetry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Below is problem 2.4 adapted from *Introduction to Electrodynamics by David Griffiths*.

Find the electric field a distance z above the center of a square loop(of side a ) carrying uniform line charge $\lambda.$

This is a question I've been struggling for a very very long time and it is bothering me so much-at least a day which leads me to suspect I am on a flawed assumption(s).

The formula for an electric field on a line charge:

$$\vec{E}\left ( \vec{r} \right )=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon _{0}}\int \frac{\lambda}{\eta ^{2}} \hat{\eta}d\mathit{l'}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon _{0}}\int\frac{\lambda \vec{\eta }}{\eta^{3}}d\mathit{l'}$$

Denote the point on the xy-plane directly beneath the field point p as the origin $\left ( 0,0,0 \right )$

Evidently, the vector between the origin $\left ( 0,0,0 \right )$ and the field point $p \left ( 0,0,z \right )$ is $ \vec{r}\left\langle 0,0,z \right\rangle $

If a point at the edge of the square loop (right most on the xy-plane)is $\left ( x,\frac{a}{2} \right )$ then the vector from the origin to this point on the edge is $\vec{r'}=\left\langle x,\frac{a}{2}\right\rangle$

Then, the separation vector $$\vec{\eta}=\vec{r}-\vec{r'}=\left\langle -x,\frac{-a}{2},z\right\rangle$$

This means that the electric field contribution due to one side of the square loop is

$$
\vec{E}\left ( \vec{r} \right ) =\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon _{0}}\int_{-a/2}^{+a/2}\frac{\lambda \left\langle -x,-a/2,z\right\rangle}{\left [ x^{2}+\left ( \frac{a}{2} \right )^{2} +z^{2}\right ]}$$

The answer given,however, is

$$\vec{E}\left ( \vec{r} \right ) =\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon _{0}}\int_{-a/2}^{+a/2}\frac{\lambda \left\langle 0,0,z\right\rangle}{\left [ x^{2}+\left ( \frac{a}{2} \right )^{2} +z^{2}\right ]}dx$$

Edit:

I understand the x and y component of the electric field cancels leaving only the z-component of the electric field. But clearly, for this to be true so that we must have

$\vec{\eta}=\vec{r}-\vec{r'}=\left \langle 0,0,z \right \rangle,$ so that $\vec{r'}=\left \langle 0,0,0 \right \rangle$ but this cannot be true for a vector from any points on edge of the corner of the loop to the field point$

Comment: Your "but clearly" is not clear to me. It's only the integral that needs to have just the $z$ term - for every point that generates a positive $x$ (or $y$) term, there is a point diametrically on the other side that cancels those terms.

Comment: @Floris Managed to figure this one out.